# Angular Flex Layout impact on child Material list

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Ok, my css skills aren't that great... So this might be something obvious, but I cannot trace the cause of this issue.

I have an Angular Material Nav List `mat-nav-list` inside a div with Angular Flex Layout on it: `fxFlexOffset.gt-sm="15%" fxFlex.gt-sm="70%"`

All is well, until I get below the xs breakpoint. List items that have a long text don't get truncated anymore and cause the width of the card to grow beyond the screen width...

When I remove the fxFlex attributes, the issue is gone.

[Stackblitz with flex](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rm4ut2?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.html)

[Stackblitz without flex](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rm4ut2-ev4hcq?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.html)

Comment: I assume this is because of the media quires.  gt-sm uses (min-width: 960px)'. Means it does not include screens below 960px, therefore flex falls back to maximum width. If you use fxFlex.sm and   fxFlex.xs it will cover all devices below 960px

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

> **l**t-sm="15%" **l**t-sm="70%"

instead of

> **g**t-sm="15%" **g**t-sm="70%"

[Check breakpoints description here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API).

Comment: No, that only reverses the behaviour on the sm breakpoint.The problem being that the text inside the mat-list item is not being truncated and thus flows out of the screen size when fxFlex is applied remains.